# Flash FLVplayback giving issues in fullscreen mode - content dissapears

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, fullscreen, flvplayback

I am working on a video playing menu set up to work in Flash player as an `exe`. I have videos playing in the background with buttons hovering above the video with which the user can then play different videos. I am not a programmer but I have an understanding of very basic actionscript3 which I often cut and paste and/or modify in small ways.

**My problem**: When launching in fullsreen mode:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

The video seems to make everything else disappear by appearing on top
of it or in other cases just causing a blank black screen.

```
this."name of FLV playback instance".fullScreenTakeOver = false;
```

Doesn't seem to be solving the problem. 
Any help would be appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered in many cases it helped to put the "name of FLV playback instance".fullScreenTakeOver = false; code in the same timeline as the FLVPlayback. I still have the black screen issue sometimes, but I am working on that now.

Found the solution for the Blank screen. It's a glitch in Flash. Put the FLVPlayback on the first frame of a movieclip. This might mean converting it to a symbol in order to nest it on the first frame.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered in many cases it helped to put the 
"name of FLV playback instance".fullScreenTakeOver = false;
code in the same timeline as the FLVPlayback. I still ahve the black screen issue sometimes, but I am working on that now.